# SVG decoding - portable solution

Tags: c++, bada

I need fully functional vector format, which i can decode to plain bitmap data in my app. It doesn't need to be SVG, but it seemed best (but other suggestions are welcome). So, i need an lib to simply rasterize SVG into plain pixel data - the simplier, the better. The problem is I need it for bada OS (it's OS for mobile phones), so i need to compile it directly with bada IDE. I found librsvg, but it seems it needs linux environment to build, so i can't use it (but i'm not sure, i don't know much about linux - if there is a way to compile it normally, tell me). I also found graphics magick, which would be perfect, but it can't correctly decode the SVG files i need (SVG support is partial). Chrome, Firefox and Inkscape opens those files perfectly. So, what lib can i use for simple rasterization of SVG files? It can be C or C++, needs to be fully open source.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/), specifically the cairomm library for C++.

Comment: I tried, but Cairo needs Pixman which is using some asm code which seems not to be portable. Bada asm compiler throws error on that. Or maybe i am doing something wrong? Is there a way to compile svg rasterize code from Cario without any asm code, or - even better - without Pixman lib?